# do we have continuous form for the verb "miss ( to feel sad because you can no longer see somebody or do something that you like)"

Tags: word-usage

> [to miss](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/miss_1?q=miss): [transitive] to feel sad because you can no longer see
>   somebody or do something that you like
>
> miss somebody/something
>
> She will be greatly missed when she leaves.
>
> What did you miss most when you were in France?
>
> miss (somebody/something) doing something I don't miss getting up at
>   six every morning!

I often hear "Who do you miss? / I miss my wife" not "Who are you missing? / I am missing my wife"

so, my question is:

do we have continuous form for the verb "**miss** (miss here means to feel sad because you can no longer see somebody or do something that you like)"?

Comment: You can use a progressive form of stative verb to express a temporal state. *I had been missing you until you came*

Comment: Example: "Now that we're divorced, I find myself missing the very things that used to annoy me about my ex-wife."

Comment: Sure, I hear people say it a lot: _I'm missing you a lot_ personally, I find the continuous form more emphasizing, like when you intend to say that you have REALLY been missing someone/thing pretty often, constantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am right. [This site](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/types.html) says "**Miss**" (to feel sad because you can no longer see somebody or do something that you like) is Non-Continuous Verb.

> to miss:
>
> John misses Sally. Non-Continuous Verb
>
> He is sad because she is not there.
>
> Debbie is missing her favorite TV program. Normal Verb
>
> She is not there to see her favorite program.

**But I don't understand why dictionaries doesn't mention this??**

Comment: A dictionary dont mention non-continuous(stative) verb because it's something that should be learnt.